# Folder in actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, package

I am learning actionscript and building a program that has grown large. I am trying to organize the .as in folders but it seems this break the static classes variables,
And you have to add the package name for each file.

Is this true need to make changes? Is there a way to put files in folder without breaking static variables? And making changes on files?

Comment: First of all, what AS are you using? (2 or 3?)

Comment: AS3 is what I am using, I am running the program from Flash pro, and editing the app with Flash Builder. the list of files in the default directory.

Comment: What you are trying to do is called refactoring and FLash Builder can do that for you very easily and efficiently. Flash pro doesn't know how to do that. In Flash builder simply move an .as file to a new location and flash builder will update everything for you including package names etc

Answer (score 0):

I'll quote adobe's site https://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/packages.html:

> "... The name of the file and the name of the class are the same. The file path corresponds to the package. ..."
>
> "... To use a class that is inside a package, import either the entire package or the specific class using an import statement. ..."
>
> "... When a package is created, internal is the default access control attribute keyword applied to all members of that package. internal package members are only visible to other members of that package. **Use the public access control attribute keyword to make package members available outside the package**. ..."

As you can read, each folder needs it's own package name. If you want to use other packages, you need to import them...
So basically I think the answer is yes, you will need to change some of your code (only by a little) so the flash builder will know where are your classes now and etc.

I hope I've understood right your question, if not try to clarify it.

Comment: I ended up adding folder name to the beginning of the class name with re-factoring, and that gave me the grouping I needed without much changes, not best way, but I still got few things to learn by figuring out. thanks all

Comment: If you think this answer helped you please at least +1 it. Also you can mark your question as answered.